# Align text and image side by side at horizontally centered level

Tags: html, css

I am trying to align horizontally text+image+text+image side by side.
The below code works when all elements are text but with images in between I cannot get it right. 
Also, all text has to always centered at 50% of the height of the largest image in the row, like in below example img1. The width I set in my CSS, but the height is auto, so variable, so I dont know how to make the text positioned at 50% of the height of the largest image. How to do it?

[image: IMG1]

```css
.merc {
 font-size:11px;
 font-weight:700;
 /*margin-left:10px;*/
 color:#777 !important;
 display:inline-block;
 max-width:35%
}

.merc-image-two img {
 display:inline-block;
 max-width:25%;
 height:auto;
 padding-left:5px;
}

.merc-image img {
 display:inline-block;
 max-width:15%;
 height:auto;
 padding-left:5px;
}

#wrapper {
 max-width:100%
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
   <div class="merc">
                    MERC MERC MERC
                </div>
                            <div class="merc-image">
        <img alt="#" src=
                    "http://lorempixel.com/50/50"></div>
  <div class="merc">
                    MERC MERC MERC
                </div>
                
                <div class="merc-image-two">
                     <img alt="#" src=
                    "http://lorempixel.com/100/100">
                </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe so:

```css
.merc {
 font-size:11px;
 font-weight:700;
 /*margin-left:10px;*/
 color:#777 !important;
 display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
 max-width:35%
}

.merc-image-two {
 display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
 max-width:25%;
 height:auto;
 padding-left:5px;
}

.merc-image {
 display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
 max-width:15%;
 height:auto;
 padding-left:5px;
}

#wrapper {
 max-width:100%
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
   <div class="merc">
                    MERC MERC MERC
                </div>
                            <div class="merc-image">
        <img alt="#" src=
                    "http://lorempixel.com/50/50"></div>
  <div class="merc">
                    MERC MERC MERC
                </div>
                
                <div class="merc-image-two">
                     <img alt="#" src=
                    "http://lorempixel.com/100/100">
                </div>
    </div>
```